# jTabbedPane opens different tab on loading

Tags: java, netbeans, jtabbedpane

First of all I'm using netbeans as my IDE and I don't know if this is causing it. When I run my program (even if I have build it and run the .jar) I think it selects the tab that was previously selected (before quiting). So if for example I close the app with the third tab selected, it starts up with that selected again. Is there a known solution for this? The selectedIndex property on the jTabbedPane is set to 0. Shouldn't this property be the default onLoad value?

Thx in advance, Jimmy

PS. BTW for some reason it didn't submit my question in Opera (?)

Comment: How do you mean "the selectedIndex property on the jTabbedPane is set to 0"?  Are you looking at this in a debugger?  In general, the value returned by `JTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()` should match the index of the selected tab, and so I'm curious how/where you're seeing a selected index of 0 when the first tab isn't selected.

Comment: I'm using netbeans so the IDE returns the default values of the properties. I guess that when the object is created it should take the default values unless stated otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here with Netbeans 6.8 and JTabbedPane. Neither *setSelectedIndex()* nor *setSelectedComponent()* makes a difference. The *getSelectedIndex()* returns the value previously set, but the pane is not selected correctly.

The reason for this is that the *SingleFrameApplication* saves it's state and restores the saved state on the next restart. This is done in the code generated by the GUI builder. 
You could see that *startup()* and *configureWindow()* methods of the SingleFrameApplication are overridden.

Workarounds:

1. You could override the *shutdown()* method as well, then modifications to the configuration will not be saved. Note that the original will still be restored, so ensure that the required configuration is saved.
2. Modifying the *startup()* method also helps:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
myView.getFrame().setVisible(true);
myView.getFrame().pack();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tabbedPaneName.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

just put that line in the place where the tabbed pane would be loaded 
if a button actuion will load the tabbed pane then put the line there 
but change tabbedPaneName to YOUR tabbed pane name.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it can be set to an index other than zero is if the Java code contains:

```
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(...);
```

So search the source code for that line and fix it.

Comment: Already did mate. The only times I found it was when I called it, so nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex()`, it's also possible to select a tab by calling `JTabbedPane.setSelectedComponent()`.  Have you searched the code for `setSelectedComponent()` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found an easy workaround.
In netbean's GUI-builder I set my tabbedpane to not enabled. Later in my program I checked if it was not enabled and in that case called MyTabbedPane.setEnabled(true); and MyTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.  Had to go back to NetBeans 7.0.1 to update a JSR 296 application and Java 7 runs it differently than previous versions did so the last tab created was always the one that had focus.  Couldn't get anything to change that in the constructor, but finally found just wrapping the same call (`setSelectedIndex()`) in a call to `invokeLater()` solves it.

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          tabMain.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
      }
    );
```